# How to fetch dimension through IMPORTXML from book website in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, xpath-2.0

This is how I get a product details using google sheets

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/Wings-of-War-James-P-Busha/9780760348529","//ul[@class='biblio-info']//li//span")
```

but I just need the Dimension. How can I fetch that?

I have been trying for 3 days but can't seem to figure it out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the XPath with DevTools (F12) of Chrome.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/Wings-of-War-James-P-Busha/9780760348529","/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/span")
```

Alternative:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/Wings-of-War-James-P-Busha/9780760348529","//ul[@class='biblio-info']//li[2]//span")
```

---

To extract only the dimensions:

```
=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/Wings-of-War-James-P-Busha/9780760348529","//ul[@class='biblio-info']//li[2]//span"),"^(.+)\|"))
```

Comment: Thank you @idfurw. I am sorry for the late reply. Was not feeling well. Both example works and I get to learn and understand more. I really appreciate it.  If I wish to only have the measurement and without the weight, can you show me how? Thanks for letting me know where to read Xpath with DevTools (F12) of Chrome too.

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: Thank you @idfurw! Initially it didn't work because of the spelling error of REGEXEXTRACT.  After I fixed it, it work! Thank you for all the examples. I am learning and I am going to study and try on others.

Comment: Sorry for my typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try (without the mass)

```
=query(split(query(IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/Wings-of-War-James-P-Busha/9780760348529","//ul[@class='biblio-info']"),"select Col2"),"|"),"select Col1")
```

or

```
=substitute(query(split(query(IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/Wings-of-War-James-P-Busha/9780760348529","//ul[@class='biblio-info']"),"select Col2"),"|"),"select Col1"),"Dimensions","")
```

or

```
=regexextract(query(split(query(IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/Wings-of-War-James-P-Busha/9780760348529","//ul[@class='biblio-info']"),"select Col2"),"|"),"select Col1"),"[0-9 x.]+")
```

or

```
=regexextract(IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/Wings-of-War-James-P-Busha/9780760348529","//ul[@class='biblio-info']//li[2]//span"),"[0-9 x.m]+")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mike. I am sorry for the late reply. I wasn't well recently. It is working and I really appreciate it. If I just need the measurement without the word, dimension, would it be possible? I tried removed "select Col2" but it doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Try the other 3 modified solutions in my answer.

Comment: Thank you @mike! It all works and thank you for all the 3 examples! I will study and learn to understand them! Thank you again for your generosity! God bless you!